# Use Only Last Line of Data Stream

Tags: bash, stream

I have this script to change the volume of my computer with a MIDI controller:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# both times in ms
CURRENT_TIME=$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))
DELAY=70

aseqdump -p "MPK mini 3" | \
while IFS=" ," read src ev1 ev2 ch label1 data1 label2 data2 rest; do

    if (( (($(date +%s%N)/1000000)) > (($CURRENT_TIME + $DELAY)) ))
    then
                   case "$ev1 $ev2 $data1 $data2" in

                           "Control change 23 $data2" )
                echo $data2 
                pamixer --set-volume $data2 ;;

                   esac
        fi
done
```

`aseqdump` sends out a stream of data for the knob changes, like this:

```
16:0   Control change          0, controller 23, value 50
16:0   Control change          0, controller 23, value 51
16:0   Control change          0, controller 23, value 52
16:0   Control change          0, controller 23, value 53
16:0   Control change          0, controller 23, value 54
```

The script has a delay to make sure it only reads a line every so often instead of constantly, but this doesn't seem to be working. No matter what I do, it always goes through the entire stream from start to finish.

Even though I added the delay, the script goes through every single line `aseqdump` produces. I want it only to read the last line the program outputs, as constantly setting the volume with every value causes a significant delay in volume change.

I also tried replacing the delay with a `sleep` command, however this seems to only make it take longer to change volume.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
aseqdump -p "MPK mini 3" | \
while IFS=" ," read src ev1 ev2 ch label1 data1 label2 data2 rest; do
        sleep 0.07
        case "$ev1 $ev2 $data1 $data2" in

<the rest of the script from above>
```

I can't figure out how to only use the most recent line, and frankly I've spent a few hours more than I'd like thinking and googling to no avail. If anyone could help, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem is, that the aseqdump  pipe stays open as long as you want to control the volume with your midi controller, if not, it would not make much sense.
So the read loop never gets a pipe stream end signal, and hangs mostly in the read line waiting for aseqdump to write again
That means, we never know in the read loop, when we have the last volume set and aseqdump is going to be silent.

I changed your script and let your read loop write the volume values to a **fifo file**, and in the background the **function checkVolume** is running and is checking the values in the fifo file with a **sample rate** overhanded by **receiver frequency**. And frequency **aseqdump** uses in writing is called **sender frequency**.

You have two kinds of volume value set, defined by mode:

set volume only, if volume finished changing, and new volume is not equal old volume
**receiver frequency must be below aseqdump's sender frequency, if not -> would cause a volume change delay!**

set volume every period, if new volume is not equal old volume -> **too high receiver frequency** would cause a volume change delay!

please read script comments for details

**start the script with:** mode: 5, which means echo sender frequency, and set volume only, if finished changing
**Please check the script, if the tmp Fifo File Path is okay for you! - second line - fifoFile=...**

```
./your_script_name [receiver frequency FLOAT] [mode INT]
```

let me know, if it worked...

```
#!/bin/bash
declare fifoFile=/tmp/controller_volume data2_ext sender_frequency receiver_frequency
declare -i PID_checkVolume current_time last_time=0 mode

trap "quit" SIGINT
trap "quit" SIGQUIT

quit ()
   {
   if [[ -d "/proc/$PID_checkVolume" ]]; then kill $PID_checkVolume; fi
   rm $fifoFile
   }
   
#--- checkVolume [receiver frequency FLOAT] [mode INT]
#--- checks the volume values with overhanded frequency from FIFO file
#--- mode INT ... mode evaluated as Bits, example mode = 3 ->  weights: Bit_2= 4, Bit_1= 2, Bit_0= 1 -> Bit_2: 0, Bit_1: 1, Bit_0: 1    
#---              Bit 0 --> set volume only, if volume finished changing, and new volume is not equal old volume
#---                        receiver frequency must be below aseqdump's sender frequency, if not -> would cause a volume change delay
#---              Bit 1 --> set volume every period -> too high frequency would cause a volume change delay             
#---              Bit 2 --> volume data includes sender frequency and echo sender frequency
checkVolume ()
   {
   local volumeSTR periodtime=$(bc <<< "scale=5; print 0, 1/$1") sender_frequency
   local -i volume_set=-1000000 volume=-1000000 mode=$2 doAset

   exec 12<$fifoFile   #-- open file descriptor 12
   
   while true; do
      doAset=0; read -u 12 volumeSTR                                         #-- reads the volume values already written to FIFO <- "51 52 53 ", after this the FIFO is empty til aseqdump writes again
      if [[ $volumeSTR == "" ]]; then                                        #-- FIFO was empty -> sender stopped writing or !!! frequency was too high and sender had no chance to set a new  value !!!
         if (( (mode & 1) > 0 && volume != volume_set )); then doAset=1; fi  #-- mode Bit_0 = 1
      else
         volumeSTR=${volumeSTR:0:-1}; volumeSTR=${volumeSTR##* }             #-- removes the last space "51 52 53" and then cuts from begin to the last space "53"
         if (( (mode & 4) > 0 )); then
            sender_frequency=${volumeSTR%%:*}; volume=${volumeSTR##*:}       #-- volumeSTR includes sender frequency "100:53" -> frequency 100, volume 53
         else volume=${volumeSTR}                                            #-- volumeSTR does not include frequency "53"-> volume 53
         fi
         if (( (mode & 2) > 0 && volume != volume_set )); then doAset=1; fi  #-- mode Bit_1 = 1
      fi
      if ((doAset)); then
         volume_set=$volume
         if (( (mode & 4) >0 )); then echo -n "aseqdump frequency: $sender_frequency, "; fi  #-- mode Bit_2 = 1
         echo "volume $volume set"
         pamixer --set-volume $volume;
      fi
      sleep $periodtime
   done
   }

mkfifo $fifoFile                              #-- makes the fifo
receiver_frequency=${1:="1"}; mode=${2:="6"}  #-- standards: receiver frequency 2, mode 6 ( echo frequency, set every period)

#-- checkVolume is started asynchronously with script parameters [receiver frequency FLOAT] [mode INT]
checkVolume "$receiver_frequency" "$mode" &

PID_checkVolume=$!                 #-- saves the PID of the checkVolume job
data2_ext=""                       #-- data2 extension - for sending frequency with volume value

aseqdump -p "MPK mini 3" | \
while IFS=" ," read -r src ev1 ev2 ch label1 data1 label2 data2 rest; do
   if (( (mode & 4) > 0 )); then                                          # mode Bit_2= 1, calculate sender frequency
      current_time=$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))
      sender_frequency=$(bc <<< "scale=3; print 1000/(${current_time}-${last_time})");
      last_time=$current_time
      data2_ext="${sender_frequency}:"
   fi
   if [[ "$ev1 $ev2 $data1" == "Control change 23" ]]; then
      echo -n "$data2_ext$data2 " > $fifoFile;                            #-- writes volume values to FIFO ->        "51 ", "52 ", "53 " 
   fi                                                                     #-- or with data2_ext, e.g. frequency 100  "100:51 ", "100:52 ", "100:53 "
done

quit #-- redundant
```

Comment: Apologies for taking ages to try this, it was a bit of a doozy to understand what you'd done and I couldn't quite get it to work right until now. This pretty much worked. All I had to do was tweak the area where you removed the trailing character in line 33, as the output of the controller is 3 characters long. Thanks a ton for your help, I wouldn't have even thought of even using a separate file and everything would have been way jankier.